# WiX Burn custom BA: How can I select appropriate language at runtime?

Tags: wix, burn

I know I can use localization variables to localize any string in a Burn bootstrapper project like I can do the same thing in the WiX MSI projects.

So, I can localize `Name` of the Bundle, `Description` of the packages, etc. But I want to select appropriate language resource at runtime of my custom BA.

Of course, I can select the language of pure UI(made using Winforms in my case) at runtime but, can I select the language of core bootstrapper data(`Name` of the Bundle, `Description` of the packages, etc) at runtime?

Thanks.